# IJCAD 2018 最新版にて、.NET よりオブジェクトを作成すると IsWriteEnabled がfalseで作成されてしまう

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD 2018 最新版にて、.NET よりオブジェクトを作成すると IsWriteEnabled がfalseで作成されてしまい、作成後修正ができません。
IsWriteEnabled を true の状態で作成できる方法を教えて下さい。

Ver.180120 では IsWriteEnabled が true で作成されるのですが
Ver.180917 だと IsWriteEnabled が false で作成されます。

ソースコードは下記の通りです。※wwという変数は連想配列オブジェクトです。

```vb
Using trans As Transaction = wdb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()

Dim blkrec As BlockTableRecord = trans.GetObject(wdb.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite)

Dim entityobj As Entity = Nothing
Dim plineobj As Polyline = New Polyline()
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
For Each wp In ww("p")
　　Dim wpt As Point2d = New Point2d(wp("x"), wp("y"))
　　plineobj.AddVertexAt(i, wpt, 0, -1, -1)
　　i += 1
Next
plineobj.Closed = If(ww("cl") = 1, True, False)
entityobj = plineobj
Dim wobjid As ObjectId = blkrec.AppendEntity(entityobj)
entityobj.Dispose()

trans.Commit()
```

Comment: IJCAD Build 190916で確認してみましたが、作成直後、作成したトランザクション内でForReadで再度開いた時、別のコマンドで作成したオブジェクトをForWriteでオープンした時などの、どのタイミングでもIsWriteEnabledプロパティがTrueになっている事を確認しました。
IsWriteEnabledプロパティがFalseになってしまう処理のコードを確認したいのですが提示可能ですか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ダウンロードサイトでは最新が、Build 180917のようなのですが、Build 190916はどちらからダウンロードできるのでしょうか？

Comment: ソースコードを質問の中に記載させていただきました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ソースコードを少し修正して作成したコマンドをIJCAD2018の最新版で実行してみましたが、オブジェクトの作成後に問題なく作成したオブジェクトの修正ができました。

```
<CommandMethod("TESTCMD")>
Public Sub TestCommand()　　

    Dim wdb = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database

    Dim ww = New List(Of Point2d)
    ww.Add(New Point2d(0, 0))
    ww.Add(New Point2d(0, 50))
    ww.Add(New Point2d(50, 50))
    ww.Add(New Point2d(50, 0))

    Dim wobjid As ObjectId = ObjectId.Null

    Using trans As Transaction = wdb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction()

        Dim blkrec As BlockTableRecord = trans.GetObject(wdb.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite)

        Dim plineobj As Polyline = New Polyline()
        '矩形のポリラインを作成する
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0
        For Each wp In ww
            plineobj.AddVertexAt(i, wp, 0, -1, -1)
            i += 1
        Next
        'ポリラインを閉じる
        plineobj.Closed = True
        '現在の空間にオブジェクトを追加
        wobjid = blkrec.AppendEntity(plineobj)
        'トランザクションにオブジェクトを登録
        trans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(plineobj, True)


        'ポリラインの修正
        plineobj.ColorIndex = 1
        plineobj.AddVertexAt(3, New Point2d(25, 25), 0, -1, -1)


        'オブジェクトを開放
        plineobj.Dispose()

        trans.Commit()
    End Using
End Sub
```

記載されていたソースコードには、作成したオブジェクトをトランザクションに登録する処理が有りませんでしたので追加してあります。
この処理を行わないとオブジェクトが開かれたままの状態になり、コマンド終了後に作成したオブジェクトを選択できない状態になったりします。

あとJCAD Build 190916についてですが、これはIJCAD2019の最新版です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。いただいたソースを実行してみたところ問題なく編集ができる状態でオブジェクトが作成できました。確認してみます。

Comment: trans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(plineobj, True)　が抜けておりました。Build 180120 で出来ていたのが謎ですが、コードを追記することで解決しました。ありがとうございました！